# FaceNotFound Exception when AddPersonFace

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cognitive-services

I have face rectangle in my database which is the result of Detect method of Microsoft Oxford.

Ex : `Top = 50 | Left = 49 | Width = 336 | Height = 336`

But when I call the method "AddPersonFace" with this specified face rectangle, I get the FaceNotFound Exception.

Ex :

```
var faceService = new FaceServiceClient("KEY");
var faces = await faceService.DetectAsync("IMG_URL");

// FaceApiException FaceNotFound Here
var faceInOxford = await faceService.AddPersonFaceAsync("GROUP_ID", "PERSON_ID", "IMG_URL", targetFace:faces[0].FaceRectangle);
```

thanks

Comment: Show the code. We can't help with this little info. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, I added a simple example which resume my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that the rectangle that Oxford gives you is too small for redetecting a face. I would suggest you to enlarge it a little and test if it works. Maybe the API needs to see the hairs, ears or the overall shape of the head to work.

However, it seems to be an unwanted behavior and you would report it to Microsoft.